# Set column collation charset for JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, character-encoding, persistence

I have a crusual question. MS SQL Server 2005 database with Latin collation stores a lot of data with non-Latin collation. I have no ability to change the collation, and the only way is to put `collate` in queries.

When I use JPA, I get a wrong charset in strings. How can I tell JPA, to use a specific collation when It work with the specific  columns? I unsuccessfully looked for some annotation and tried to use  `collate`  in queries like

`SELECT t COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS FROM TXTTable t WHERE t.textid = :textid`.

Please, help me!
THANK YOU TOO MUCH!

Comment: Do you need the collation after the select or in the `WHERE` clause?  If you need it on the `WHERE`, you need to put the `COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` there (i.e. `SELECT t.t FROM TXTTable t WHERE t.textid COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS = :textid COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.  Your query just collates `t` as Cyrillic so that other queries referencing this return set will use that collation.

Comment: Perhaps what is [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634657/collate-hint-on-querydsl-jpa) helps. I understand that this question is very old, and am commenting to aide future visitors.