# Collate hint on QueryDSL- JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, querydsl

There is a way to execute it with QueryDSL? (**bold part**):

SELECT * FROM Venue WHERE Name Like '%cafe%' **COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI**

I am using JPA with hibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `addFlag(QueryFlag.Position position, String flag)` method, documented [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/ProjectableSQLQuery.html#addFlag(com.mysema.query.QueryFlag.Position,%20java.lang.String)).

Something similar to the following should do what you want:

```
query.addFlag(QueryFlag.Position.END, "COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI");
```

In response to your question in the comments, if you require a solution that supports more than one predicate, you could use `BooleanTemplate`'s `create(String template, Object one)` method, documented [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.1/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/template/BooleanTemplate.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

Something similar to the following should do what you want:

```
BooleanTemplate.create("{0} COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI", venue.name.like("%cafe%"));
```

Your query should look something like:

```
query
.from(venue)
.where(BooleanTemplate.create("{0} COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI", venue.name.like("%cafe%"))
.and(BooleanTemplate.create("{0} COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI", venue.name2.like("%milk%"))))
.list(venue.name, venue.name2);
```

Comment: There is a solution that supports more than one predicate? ex.:
SELECT * FROM Venue WHERE Name Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI and  Name2 Like '%milk%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI

Comment: how would you use the collate statement in an `orderBy` clause?